# GPU - PSU - motherboard problems

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, gpu, hardware-rec

1. First Problem. So I wanted to buy a GPU (MSI GEFORCE GT 1030), but
   when I started researching my power supply I realized that my power
   supply (180w) doesn't have enough power output for the GPU
   (recommended 300w)..
2. Second Problem. After that, I just thought I should buy a new power
   supply but then I found out that my motherboard has a 14pin
   connector, which is impossible to find nowadays.
   So is it possible to find a GPU that will run on my current power supply (hk280-22pp)? Or should I just buy a 24pin to 14pin adapter and a new power supply?

Comment: What motherboard do you have?

Comment: All I could find: https://imageresize.org/image/bad57191-8d0d-4722-9dfe-4b0292364da7

Comment: Don't you have any documentation that accompanied your computer? It does look like a Lenovo Pre-Built? I was wondering whenever you actually have a slot for that graphics card. But it does look like H81 motherboards do feature PCI-E slots. 14 pins hasn't been a standard that I know of. For a long time it has been 20+4. It's likely that it's vendor specific so you will probably have to find a suitable adapter cable if you want to keep that motherboard. Even if you go that route your motherboard might not be able to deliver enough power for that graphics card. You really need to check the docs.

Comment: The pc is pre-built it's a Lenovo ThinkCentre E73

Comment: The PCI slot supplies up to [60W according to documentation](https://support.lenovo.com/de/en/solutions/pd029623) and the card uses around [30W](https://de.msi.com/pdf/presale_v2/GeForce-GT-1030-2GH-LP-OC). So your board should be able to run the card. As such it's up to you to decide whenever you want to go for an adapter (be sure its a suitable one) or to check whenever there are alternative PSUs available from Lenovo for that model.